# Updating Mongo documents

Tags: mongodb

I would like to update a collection by transforming all documents from this form:

```
{
"_id" : "somestring i made",
"value" : {
    "a" : 0.42361499999999996,
    "b" : 3,
    "c" : "foo",
    "d" : "bar"
}
}
```

To this form (with new id's):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("77d987f6dsf6f76sa7676df"),
"a" : 0.42361499999999996,
"b" : 3,
"c" : "foo",
"d" : "bar"

}
```

So essentially take the fields out of the object "value" and reset the id to a real document id.

Comment: if you are creating a new id, why you just don't create another document and delete the old document?

Comment: what's so hard with that? read and remove `value` from the documents and then add the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the document , convert to required format , remove the old doc and again insert the modified one . 
Something like

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    var obj = { a : doc.value.a, 
                b : doc.value.b,
                c : doc.value.c,
                d : doc.value.d};
     db.collection.remove(doc);
     db.collection.insert(obj);
});
```

Comment: do you have a version that does not block? I have seen this solution but thought this locks the collection while updating